# MongoDB Group on Multiple Levels

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of event data that I'd like to perform a aggregate/grouping on to summarize event data into a single result. What I'm having an issue with is just getting my head wrapped around how to organize the data the way I want to return the result.

sample data:

db.events.find({})

```
{
    eventId : "abc",
    eventDate : 1420088400000,
    eventLength : 1800000,
    eventStart : 59100000,
    attendees : [
        "userA",
        "userB",
        "userC"
    ],
    otherData : "...",
    etc : "..."
},{
    eventId : "def",
    eventDate : 1421557200000,
    eventLength : 3600000,
    eventStart : 36000000,
    attendees : [
        "userA",
        "userG",
        "userZ"
    ],
    otherData : "...",
    etc : "..."
},{
    eventId : "ghi",
    eventDate : 1420088400000,
    eventLength : 7200000,
    eventStart : 45000000,
    attendees : [
        "userD",
        "userE",
        "userA"
    ],
    otherData : "...",
    etc : "..."
}
```

Basically the date's/time's/and length are all stored as long or int representing the milliseconds, so adding eventDate + eventStart would give you the date and start time in UTC. Adding eventDate + eventStart + eventLength would give you the event end time in UTC.

What I'm trying to do is create and aggregate that allows me to $match on a userId in the attendees (no prob here), but display a grouping of data by day/week/month/year/overall.

So sample result would be for example (and this isn't accurate to the times in the sample data above, but looking for how to script this grouping..)

```
{
    userId : "userA",
    req : 75.0,
    totals : [
        {
            period : "day",
            events : 2,              //this means two event for today
            eventsLength : 7200000,  //$sum of the 2 events length
        },{
            period : "week",
            events : 3,              //this means 3 events in the week
            eventsLength : 9600000,  //$sum of the 3 events length
        },{
            period : "month",
            events : 8,              //this means 8 events in the month
            eventsLength : 15000000, //$sum of the 8 events length
        },{
            period : "year",
            events : 15,             //this means 15 events in the year
            eventsLength : 15000000, //$sum of the 15 events length
        },{
            period : "overall",
            events : 23,             //this means 23 events lifetime
            eventsLength : 72000000, //$sum of the 23 events length
        }
    ]
}
```

So for each "period" I basically want to keep a running total and $sum up the eventLength and the number of events. The "req" means given the current date, the user has completed 3/4 events (75%). It's independent of the totals, basically it's just a percentage to say the target is 4 events a week and here's your percent complete. So you see in the "week" period, they only have 3 out of 4 as the target.

In my aggregate I've tried a combination of $match, $project, and $group to try and make this output, but I was hoping someone could help with the grouping for a running total..

I have the date/milliseconds calculated out for each period given a current date, so I already have that predetermined as variables, I just don't know how to structure the aggregate/grouping to produce this result..

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Minor nitpick in the construction of your question ( constructive criticism ). The result data structure you consider is not valid for any language, but let's just assume JSON, so not valid. Perhaps you mean an array of each grouping. More on the question itself, you kind of can do this at multiple depths, but it may not be very practical in a single statement. The other unknown here is the "req". How do you know the 3/4 based on the data model provide? And to which metric does it apply? "week", "day", "year"? It all makes a clearer question. But consider the statements also.

Comment: Hi Neil, yes correct rather than a collection of periods, it'd be an array.. I was hoping with each array element I could run a group, event if I had 5 group statements to add each element of data to the totals array.. this way it would appear as a "running total" however it'd be 5 results added to the resulting data set..

Comment: the "req" or requirement, would be based on the week the current date falls in, M->Sun (ISO).

Comment: Here's also whats available as variables to the statement, built at a string first, vars replaced, then ran..

Comment: dayStart: 1421643600000
dayEnd: 1421729999999
weekStart: 1421643600000
weekEnd: 1422248399999
monthStart: 1420088400000
monthEnd: 1422766799999
yearStart: 1420088400000
yearEnd: 1451624399999

Comment: On re-read it should actually be possible with the aggregation framework. Not sure of the overall scope of your data. Read the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)  operator documentation and practice your date math around that reasoning. It's not simple though. Love to help, but going to sleep. I'll keep the link open. But maybe someone else will jump in and be the hero. It's a good and tough question to explain.

Comment: Thanks Neil, appreciate your feedback!

Comment: One last thing though. All your numbers are strings. You cannot do math on strings. Answers including suggestions would be fine, but it would be better if you fixed that yourself and presented it as such. Ciao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of messing around with this yesterday, I have this solution which isn't the exact output I was looking for where I have totals as an array with each "period" or array element as a collection of summed up totals, however this outputs a collection, segmented by "period (day/week/month/year/overall)", with accumulated totals for each..

```
{
    $match: {userId : "ABC123"}
},{
    $project : {
    _id : 0,
    d : {$cond:{if:{$and:[{$gte:["$eventDate", "${dayStart}"]},{$lte:["$eventDate", "${dayEnd}"]}]}, 
        then: {d : "$eventLength", c : {"$literal" : 1}}, 
        else: null }
    },
    w : {$cond:{if:{$and:[{$gte:["$eventDate","${weekStart}"]},{$lte:["$eventDate", "${weekEnd}"]}]}, 
        then: {d : "$eventLength", c : {"$literal" : 1}}, 
        else: null }
    },
    m : {$cond:{if:{$and:[{$gte:["$eventDate","${monthStart}"]},{$lte:["$eventDate","${monthEnd}"]}]}, 
        then: {d : "$eventLength", c : {"$literal" : 1}}, 
        else: null }
    },
    y : {$cond:{if:{$and:[{$gte:["$eventDate","${yearStart}"]},{$lte:["$eventDate","${yearEnd}"]}]}, 
        then: {d : "$eventLength", c : {"$literal" : 1}}, 
        else: null }
    },
    o : {$cond:{if:{$lte:["$eventDate","${yearEnd}"]}, 
        then: {d : "$eventLength", c : {"$literal" : 1}}, 
        else: null }
    }
}
},{
$group : {
    _id : null,
    day_d : {$sum : "$d.d"},
    day_c : {$sum : "$d.c"},
    week_d : {$sum : "$w.d"},
    week_c : {$sum : "$w.c"},
    month_d : {$sum : "$m.d"},
    month_c : {$sum : "$m.c"},
    year_d : {$sum : "$y.d"},
    year_c : {$sum : "$y.c"},
    over_d : {$sum : "$o.d"},
    over_c : {$sum : "$o.c"}
} 
},{
$project : {
    _id : 0,
    day : {events : "$day_c", millisTotal : "$day_d"},
    week : {events : "$week_c", millisTotal : "$week_d"},
    month : {events : "$month_c", millisTotal : "$month_d"},
    year : {events : "$year_c", millisTotal : "$year_d"},
    overall : {events : "$over_c", millisTotal : "$over_d"},
    req : {
        $cond : { 
            if : { $gte : ["$week_c", 4]}, then : 100, 
            else : {
                $cond : {
                    if : { $eq : ["$week_c", 3] }, then : 75,
                    else : {
                        $cond : {
                            if : { $eq : ["$week_c", 2] }, then : 50,
                            else : {
                                $cond : {
                                    if : { $eq : ["$week_c", 1] }, then : 25,
                                    else : 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This generates an output that looks like this..

```
{
day : {
    events : 1,
    millisTotal : 7200000
},
week : {
    events : 2,
    millisTotal : 14400000
},
month : {
    events : 17,
    millisTotal : 87345000
},
year : {
    events : 17,
    millisTotal : 87345000
},
overall : {
    events : 18,
    millisTotal : 92745000
},
req : 50
}
```

One thing I noticed is its nearly impossible to $project back into an array element, such that I could have a "totals : []" with each period collection as an array element, however this works for now.. If anyone has feedback or a better way to accomplish this, I'll leave this open for a bit and see if any better answers come about.. The reason I'd like this as an array of totals, is the logic that uses this output can be more dynamic, and not expect a specific set of "keys" as day/week/month/year/overall.